Pulse generation from a constant current source
I need to generate a biphasic pulse as shown below.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
The specifications of the pulse is given below.
Amplitude 0~10mA
Pulse width 10~500µs
Constant inter-pulse delay  = 100 µs
Pulses Per Train = 1~10
Pulse Repetition Frequency(PRF) 30~150 Hz
May I know is it possible to generate a pulse as shown below using a constant current source.
The current source circuit is given below.

If not possible can you suggest a circuit for generating the pusle
EDIT 2:I THINK WE CAN USE HBRIDGE FOR GENERATING THE CURRENT PULSE
Please see the circuit below.

May I know your comments

What rise/fall time? Compliance (voltage) range? Precision? And, I assume your question is more interesting / more in depth than merely "is it possible"?

Use a pair of BJTs (NPB & PNP). It should be bidirectional.

Which resistor in your schematic is the load?  What is the load in the final applicaiton?  For the final design you want, is one terminal of the load connected to a common node, eg; GND?

@Antonio51,Can please explain with a circuit

@TimWilliamsc,this is a POC .I don't have RT,FT spec

@FabioBarone,I don't know about final design.This is POC.I need to have a circuit which generate the above waveform.

@Confused  What is "POC", is it "Proof of Concept"?  Also, it is rather important to know if one terminal of the load will be connected to a common node (GND) at all times - this is often a requirement, and if true will preclude some solutions.  Is the LOAD a 2-terminal device?  Equally important are the other questions here in the comments; the answers will help narrow down the possible solution space (which to ignore and which to explore) - without those answers then far too many solutions are possible which will only waste your time, as well as everyone elses.

@FabioBarone,Yes POC is proof of concept.One end of the load is connected to GND

@Confused R1 is the "load" in this design, neither end of which is connected to ground. Fabio's points about grounding are important and valid, and your answers are inconsistent with your own design.

@SimonFitch,I don't have any info about load.My first intention is to generate a waveform as shown in question.

User selectable 0-10 mA? Symmetrical or asymmetrical?

Not user selectable Amplitude is fixed.You can see that in the first image."A" is the amplitude parameter.

The circuit below is worth exploring.  R1 is the load.  V3 is the signal generator of the current waveform you want.  Scale of current per volt of input is set by R2, in this case 1V == 0.1Amps.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Input signal:

Output, current in R1:

For an input of 0.1V, the output will be a current of 10mA.  You simply provide the reference signal to node [Vin], and the circuit will generate the corresponding current in R1.

The Output, current in R1 diagram appears to show "spikes" in the current up to approximately +/- 18 mA on some transitions of the input signal. What is the cause of the "spikes" and if you zoom in on the X scale what is the time duration of the "spikes"?

@ChesterGillon  This is just the result of the simulator I happened to use that is associated with this website, "CircuitLab".  I used the default models for op-amp and BJTs, and made no attempt to optimise or adjust in any way.  First time I used this simulator, I am far more familiar with LTspice.  I suspect the slew-rate limit of the op-amp may be a factor here, these spikes occur when the current changes polarity, in which case the opamp output becomes disconnected as it turns off one BJT and turns on the other.  The signal is 1kHz.

@ChesterGillon  Possible solutions are: 1. Put a dv/dt limiter at the input to the the op-amp; 2. change the output stage from class B to class AB.  3. Remove the output buffer altogether if the output current required is within the capability of the op-amp.  But given the OP has not provided much in the way of specifications or requirements then I was reluctant to spend much effort sorting out problems that may or may not exist.

@FabioBarone,How to get inter pulse delay of 100us

Use a timer, or square wave generator with a settable duty cycle.   One for the positive pulse, another for the negative pulse, and add the outputs together.  Do a search on this site for such signal generators, you will find many different solutions.
